# Could not use rails 4.2.2 with refinerycms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, refinerycms

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionpack":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 4.2.2) ruby depends on
      railties (= 4.2.2) ruby depends on
        actionpack (= 4.2.2) ruby
```

I am using rails 4.2.2 and unable use refinerycms with this, please could you help me.

Comment: Please provide more info. This error does not state the conflicting version (need more of the error)

Answer (score 0):

Refinery CMS requires at least Rails 4.2.3. If you perform the following:

```
gem install rails --version 4.2.5
rails _4.2.5_ new my_app -m http://refinerycms.com/t/3.0.0
```

This will generate a new application for you with Rails 4.2.5 (the current latest version).

If you already have an application, make sure you specify rails 4.2.3 or above in your Gemfile and run:

```
bundle update
```